# The commits extracted from GitHub API are different than the commits I get from git.Repo for the same project

Tags: python, git, commit, pull-request

What I am trying to do is: I want to extract the name of classes that have been modified in a pull request. To do that, I do the following:

From GitHub API:

1) I extract all the pull requests for one project

2) I extract all the commits for each pull request

3) I keep only the first commit and last commit for each pull request.

Since at this point, I don't know how to extract the list of modified classes between these two commits per pull request, I use 'git' package, like this:

I cloned `gson` repository in `D:\\projects\\gson`

```
import git
repo = git.Repo("D:\\projects\\gson") 
commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())
temp = []
for x in commits_list[0].diff(commits_list[-1]):
    if (x.a_path == x.b_path):
        if x.a_path.endswith('.java'):
            temp.append(x.a_path)
    else:
        if x.b_path.endswith('.java'):
           temp.append(x.b_path)
```

Here is how I extract commits form GitHub API:

```
projects = [ {'owner':'google', 'repo':'gson', 'pull_requests': []}]

def get(url):

    global nb

    PARAMS = {
    'client_id': '----my_client_id---',
    'client_secret': '---my_client_secret---',
    'per_page': 100,
    'state': 'all' #open, closed, all
    }

    result = requests.get(url = url, params=PARAMS)
    nb+=1

    if(not (result.status_code in [200, 304])):
        raise Exception('request error', url, result, result.headers)

    data = result.json()
    while 'next' in result.links.keys():
        result = requests.get(url = result.links['next']['url'], 
    params=PARAMS)
        data.extend(result.json())
        nb+=1

    return data


 def get_pull_requests(repo):

    url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{}/pulls'.format(repo)

    result = get(url)

    return result

def get_commits(url):

    result = get(url)

    return result

 for i,project in enumerate(projects):
    project['pull_requests'] = 
 get_pull_requests('{}/{}'.format(project['owner'],project['repo']))
    for p in project['pull_requests']:
        p['commits'] = get_commits(p['commits_url'])
    print('{}/{}'.format(project['owner'],project['repo']), ':', 
len(project['pull_requests']))
```

Each of these two codes works. The problem is, I get 287 commits from GitHub API, but only 86 commits from git.Repo for the same project. When I try to match these commits, less then 40 commits matches.

Questions:

1) Why am I getting different commits for the same project?

2) Which one is correct and I should use?

3) Is there a way I can know what commits are for what pull request using Git.Repo ?

4) Is there a way I can extract the modified classes between two commits in GitHub API?

5) Dose anyone know of a better way of extracting modified classes per pull request?

I know this is a long post, but I tried to be specific here. The answer to any of these questions would be very much appreciated.